# Convergence of coeffiecients of element in infinite symmetric group algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathbb{C}S_\infty$ - infinite symmetric group algebra (generated by all finite permutations, i.e. $\mathbb{C} S_\infty = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{C} S_n$). Turn it into $C^*$-algebra by identity $\sigma^* = \sigma^{-1}$ for every permutation $\sigma \in S_\infty$. Take completion of $\mathbb{C}S_\infty$ by spectral norm $||x||_{spec}^2=r(x^*x)$ where $r(x)=\sup\{|\lambda| :\lambda \in \mathbb{C}, x-\lambda 1$ - not invertible$\}$ - spectral radius of element $x$.  Let $x \in \mathbb{C} S_\infty$ - some element of $(\mathbb{C}S_\infty, ||\cdot||_{spec})$, imagine it like $x=\sum_{\sigma \in S_\infty} \sigma \lambda_\sigma $ it is true that $\sum_{\sigma \in S_\infty} |\lambda_\sigma|^2$ convergence?

Comment: You write «in the trivial way» but you mean «in the obvious way».

Comment: I don't know those notations. $\mathbb{C} S_\infty$ means the permutation group of complex sequences ? and implicitly we are considering the algebra of linear operators ? and the problem is to understand that the given spectral norm implies that we are in $l^2$ and the $C^*$ algebra of bounded convolution operators on $l^2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use that technique to construct a C$^*$-algebra. The spectral radius does not give a norm in an arbitrary $*$-algebra.

For an easy example, consider $\mathbb C[x]$ with complex conjugation as an involution. The only invertible polynomials are the constants, so for any polynomial 
$p$ of degree at least 1
$$
\sigma(p^*p)=\mathbb C.
$$
The spectrum is not very useful when you have almost no inverses.

When you have a group algebra, to get a C$^*$-algebra you need to induce the norm via a representation. The two canonical ones are the left regular representation (thus giving you the reduced C$^*$-algebra of the group), and the universal representation (giving the universal group algebra).

In the case of the reduced C$^*$-algebra, one can show that $C^*_r(\Gamma)$ can be identified with some convolution operators:
$$
C^*_r(\Gamma)\subset\{x\in\ell^2(\Gamma):\ \forall y\in\ell^2(\Gamma),\ x*y\in\ell^2(\Gamma)\}.
$$
So in that case the elements of the group algebra are indeed given by properly chosen $\ell^2$-sequences, but not all.

Comment: You right, thanks! I think current formulation of my question is more understandable. Can you answer on it?

Comment: @kp9r4d, your «reformulation» of the question turned the perfectly nice answer of Martin into something with no relation to the question! It is much, much better to do the sort of change you did preserving the original formulation.

Comment: I agree with Mariano in principle, but my answer already addresses (in its last paragraph) the new version of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I did like you advise.
@Martin Argerami, thanks, I get answers to all my questions!

Comment: @Martin Argerami Can you comment another my "microquestion"? I correctly understand: between $\ell_2(S_\infty)$ and $C_r^*(S_\infty)$ exist canonical bijection?

Comment: No, there isn't. As I mentioned in the answer, you can identify $C_r^*(S_\infty)$ with the $\ell^2$ sequences that are bounded convolution operators. In other words, not every sequence from $x\in\ell^2(S_\infty)$ gives you an element $\sum x_\sigma\,\sigma.$

Comment: @Martin Argerami Ok. And $C_r^* (S_\infty)$ like subset of $\ell^2(S_\infty)$ is not weakly closed, right?

Comment: No, it isn't. Note that it contains a dense subset (the finite sequences) so it cannot be even normed closed.